# pytest fixture yield list of dict throws "yield_fixture function has more than one 'yield':"

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have defined a fixture like :

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def mock_yield_data(self):
        for data in [
            {
                1: 2, 2: 3
            },
            {
                2: 4, 4: 5
            },
        ]:
            yield data
```

and a test method like :

```
    def test_fixture(self, mock_yield_data):
        for data in mock_yield_data:
            assert data
```

The assert is successful but the `teardown` throws, `yield_fixture function has more than one 'yield':`.

```
==================================================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of TestClass.test_fixture _________________________________________________________________________
yield_fixture function has more than one 'yield':
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last section of the [pytest.yieldfixture](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.7/yieldfixture.html) documentation:

> - usually yield is used for producing multiple values. But **fixture functions can only yield exactly one value**. Yielding a second fixture value will get you an error. It’s possible we can evolve pytest to allow for producing multiple values as an alternative to current parametrization. For now, you can just use the normal fixture parametrization mechanisms together with yield-style fixtures.

With a memory footprint that small, you should just return the entire thing:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_yield_data(self):
    return [
        {
            1: 2, 2: 3
        },
        {
            2: 4, 4: 5
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your fixture may only have one `yield`. However, you may pass in [parameters](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) to the fixture, which will run the fixture for each parameter.

```
all_data = [
    {
        1: 2, 2: 3
    },
    {
        2: 4, 4: 5
    }
]

@pytest.fixture(params=all_data)
def mock_yield_data(self, request):
    yield request.param
```

Comment: your example is even better than the docs!

Comment: This will automatically test for both params. How can I test by index? Means I only want the first data to be assert

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you just have one item to yield, you don't need the params in the fixture, just `yield all_data[0]`.